# Implementing caching of services in Domain project being used by a Web API

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, caching

**My question is**: how do I implement caching in my domain project, which is working like a normal stack with the repository pattern.

I have a setup that looks like the following:

- ASP.NET MVC website
- Web API
- Domain project (using IoC, with Windsor)

My domain project for instance have:

- IOrderRepository.cs
- OrderRepository.cs
- Order.cs

My ASP.NET MVC website calls the Web API and gets back some DTO classes. My Web API then maps these objects to business objects in my domain project, and makes the application work.

Nowhere in my application have I implemented caching.

**Where should be caching be implemented?**

I thought about doing it inside the methods in the OrderRepository, so my `Get`, `GetBySpecification` and `Update` methods has to call some generic cache handler injected by the OrderRepository.

This obviously gives some very ugly code, and isn't very generic.

**How to maintain the cache?**

Let's say we have a cache key like "OrderRepostory_123". When I call the Update method, should I call cacheHandler.Delete("OrderRepository_123") ? Because that seems very ugly as well

**My own thoughts...**

I can't really see a decent way to do it besides some of the messy methods I have described. Maybe I could make some cache layer, but I guess that would mean my WebAPI wouldn't call my OrderRepository anymore, but my CacheOrderRepository-something?

Comment: Do you need to cache globally or just for a session?  Is your repository in memory or do you use a database?  Is performance your main motivation for using caching?

Comment: Globally is what I need for this cache. The repository uses a database. And yes, performance is my only motivator for now. Thanks for making these things clear!

Comment: If you happen to be using EF you can set up caching on it

Comment: @Steve I do, but that would only cache on my domain -> database connection. That would not solve any problems between Web API -> Domain project :) But that is a valid and good point

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Personally, I am not a fan of including caching directly in repository classes.  A class should have a single reason to change, and adding caching often adds a second reason.  Given your starting point you have at least two likely reasonable options:

1. Create a new class that adds caching to the repository and exposes the same interface
2. Create a new service interface that uses one or more repositories and adds caching

In my experience #2 is often more valuable, since the objects you'd like to cache as a single unit may cross repositories.  Of course, this depends on how you have scoped your repositories.  A lot may depend on whether your repositories are based on aggregate roots (ala DDD), tables, or something else.

Answer (score 1):

There are probably a million different ways to do this, but it seems to me (given the intent of caching is to improve performance) implementing the cache similar to a repository pattern - where the domain objects interact with the cache instead of the database, then perhaps a background thread could keep the database and cache in sync, and the initial startup of the app pool would fill the cache (assuming eager loading is desired).  A whole raft of technical issues start to crop up, such as what to do if the cache is modified in a way that violates a database constraint.  Code maintenance becomes a concern where any data structure related concerns possibly need to be implemented in multiple places.  Concurrency issues start to enter the fray.  Just some thoughts...

Answer (score 1):

SQLCacheDependency with System.Web.Caching.Cache, http://weblogs.asp.net/andrewrea/archive/2008/07/13/sqlcachedependency-i-think-it-is-absolutely-brilliant.aspx . This will get you caching that gets invalidated based on other systems applying updates also.

Answer (score 0):

there are multiple levels of caching depending on the situation however if you are looking for generic centralized caching with low number of changes I think you will be looking for EF second level caching and for more details check the following http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/hh394143.aspx

Also you can use caching on webapi level

Kindly consider if MVC and WebAPI the network traffic if they are hosted in 2 different data centers

and for huge read access portal you might consider Redis http://Redis.io

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you want to use a .NET caching mechanism rather than a distributed cache like Redis or Memcache.  I would recommend using the `System.Runtime.Caching.MemoryCache` class instead of the traditional `System.Web.Caching.Cache` class.  Doing this allows you to create your caching layer independent of your MVC/API layer because the MemoryCache has no dependencies on System.Web.

Caching your DTO objects would speed up your application greatly.  This prevents you from having to wait for data to be assembled from a cache that mirrors your data layer.  For example, requesting Order123 would only require a single cache read rather than to several reads to any FK data.  Your caching layer would of course need to contain the logic to invalidate the cache on UPDATEs you perform.  A recommended way would be to retrieve the cached order object and modify its properties directly, then persist to the DB asynchronously.